# Python: Error when trying to find indexes to a matrix

Tags: python, list

I have this code that creates a matrix filled with zeros. I want to replace some of the zeros with a "sign" which is given when creating a snake object. I then want to replace the zeros in the matrix with my sign without increasing the total amount of elements in the matrix.

With my "growth" function in the snake class I want to make sure that only zeros is overwritten but I get the error:

```
ValueError: (1, 4) is not in list
```

When I'm sure that position actually do exist! The error code is different each time I run the program since the cordinates are generated on random. Here's my code:

```
class field:
 def __init__(self):

    self.table= [ [ "0" for i in range(10) ] for j in range(10) ]

  def printfield(self):
     for row in self.table:
            print (row)


Class snake:

  def __init__(self,sign):
    self.sign = sign
    self.x = random.randint(1,9) 
    self.y = random.randint(1,9)    

    field.table[self.x][self.y] = sign


  def growth(self, list, index, element):
    if list[index] != 0:
        return False
    else:
        field.table[self.x-v*b][self.y-v*c] = element


  def increase(self,p,b,c):                                               

        for v in range(p+1):
                self.growth(field.table,field.table.index((self.x-v*b,self.y-v*c)), self.sign)
```

Comment: Please god don't ever name your variable **list**.

Comment: oops, sorry. Well, the thing is that my code is 120lines long so I didn't dare to post it all, but I got the answers I wanted below so fortunately it worked out! 
Ps. It's not actually named list in my real code, I just thought I should translate it to english before posting it here:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing your indices in the two-dimensional list with values in the list. The statement

```
field.table.index((self.x-v*b, self.y-v*c))
```

looks for a **value** of (in your given error case) `(1, 4)` inside of the list `field.table`, which is of course not there. What you probably want is accessing `field.table[1][4]`. You could just pass the tuple as a variable to `growth` and use its elements as indices for the list, or pass `field.table[self.x-v*b]` as the list to growth and `self.y-v*c` as the index to access on that list.

Also, you are filling the list with `"0"`s but checking against `0` inside your `growth` function.

Comment: Thanks!! Very nice explanation, I get it now! I will try to access it with field.table[self.x-v*b][self.y-v*c] instead. 
And thank you so much for pointing that out, I hadn't thought of that at all! Is it possible to just change the if clause to != "0" ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from your increase method not your growth method. It happens when you call `table.index((self.x-v*b,self.y-v*c))`. It's not clear to me what your trying to do when you call index table, but the index method returns the position of a value in the list. So for example:

```
>>> A = [0, 1, 5, 10]
>>> A.index(5)
2
```

table seems to be a list of lists of ints so when you call `table.index((1, 4))`, the tuple `(1, 4)` is not found in index. Maybe you want `table[1][4]`?

Update:

I thinks this is what you want:

`self.growth(field.table, (self.x-v*b, self.y-v*c), self.sign)`

and replace `field.table[self.x-v*b][self.y-v*c]` with `field.table[index[0]][index[1]]`

`(self.x-v*b, self.y-v*c)` is the index you want and once you pass it into growth, you need to refer to it using it's argument name.

Comment: I wanted to see if the position in the list of lists, that the growth method will add the element to, is a zero or something else. If it's something else I want it to return the False value. I hope that made it a bit clearer!

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time, Bi rico. I will try out everything you suggested!